# Convert jpa generated sources to dot notation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

The following generated sources exist:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Profile.class)
public abstract class Profile_ {

   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Profile, String> zip;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Profile, String> lastName;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Profile, String> address;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Profile, String> address2;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Profile, String> city;
   public static volatile SetAttribute<Profile, ProfilePayors> payors;
}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(ProfilePayors.class)
public abstract class ProfilePayors_ {

  public static volatile SingularAttribute<ProfilePayors, Boolean> isDefault;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<ProfilePayors, ProfilePayorsPK> id;
}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(ProfilePayorsPK.class)
public abstract class ProfilePayorsPK_ {

   public static volatile SingularAttribute<ProfilePayorsPK, Long> profileId;
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<ProfilePayorsPK, Long> payorId;
}
```

I would like to utilize the generated sources to build a type-safe object then convert it to a dot notation string.

Example 1: asking for the `Profile` -> `Payors` -> `IsDefault`

Output: `Profile.Payors.IsDefault`

Example 2: asking for the `Profile` -> `Payors` -> `Id` (ignore) -> `ProfileId`

Output: `Profile.Payors.ProfileId`

I do not have access to the entity manager to create a criteria builder. How do you write a class which takes in a generated source and builds out a path returning a string in dot notation?

**Example Usage:**

`String x = from(Profile.class).get(Profile_.payors).get(ProfilePayors_.id).get(ProfilePayorsPK_.profileId).buildDotNotation()`